# Assignment Operation on a returned local variable

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to add 2 polynomial objects and then assign it to the third one, Here's the code for the operator overloading:

```
class Polynomial {
private:
    int* exponents;
    float* coeffs;
    int size;

public:
    Polynomial() {
        size = 10;
        exponents = new int[size];
        coeffs = new float[size];
    }
    Polynomial(int s) {
        size = s;
        exponents = new int[size];
        coeffs = new float[size];
    }
    Polynomial(const Polynomial& obj) {
        size = obj.size;
        exponents = new int[size];
        coeffs = new float[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.size; i++) {
            exponents[i] = obj.exponents[i];
            coeffs[i] = obj.coeffs[i];
        }
    }
    ~Polynomial() {
        delete[] exponents;
        exponents = nullptr;
        delete[] coeffs;
        coeffs = nullptr;
    }
    int* SizeAdjustexp(int*& arr, int size) {
        int* newarr = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            newarr[i] = arr[i];
        }
        delete[]arr;
        return newarr;
    }

    float* SizeAdjustCoeff(float*& arr, int size) {
        float* newarr = new float[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            newarr[i] = arr[i];
        }
        delete[] arr;
        return newarr;
    }

    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, Polynomial& P);

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Polynomial& P);

   const Polynomial  operator +( const Polynomial& obj) const  {
        int terms = this->size + obj.size;
        float* sum = new float[terms];
        int* sumexp = new int[terms];

        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            sumexp[temp] = exponents[i];
            sum[temp] = coeffs[i];
            temp++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < obj.size; i++) {
            sumexp[temp] = obj.exponents[i];
            sum[temp] = obj.coeffs[i];
            temp++;
        }

        terms = temp;
        int max = sumexp[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < terms; i++) { // Sorting exponents and coeff in descending order
            max = sumexp[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j < terms; j++) {
                if (sumexp[j] > max) {
                    swap(sumexp[j], sumexp[i]);
                    swap(sum[i], sum[j]);
                    max = sumexp[i];

                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < terms; i++) { // Adding terms with same exponents
            for (int j = i + 1; j < terms; j++) {
                if (sumexp[i] == sumexp[j]) {
                    sum[i] = sum[i] + sum[j];
                    for (int k = i + 1; k < terms; k++) {
                        sum[k] = sum[k + 1];
                        sumexp[k] = sumexp[k + 1];
                    }
                    terms--;
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
        int maxSize = terms;

        Polynomial SumObj (maxSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {
            SumObj.exponents[i] = sumexp[i];
            SumObj.coeffs[i] = sum[i];
        }
        delete[]sum;
        sum = nullptr;
        delete[]sumexp;
        sumexp = nullptr;
        return  SumObj;
    }
   Polynomial& operator=(const Polynomial& obj) {
        size = obj.size;
        exponents = new int[size];
        coeffs = new float[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.size; i++) {
            exponents[i] = obj.exponents[i];
            coeffs[i] = obj.coeffs[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }

int main() {
    Polynomial P1, P2, M1, A1;
    cin >> P1;
    cout << "The first Polynomial is " << endl;
    cout << P1;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> P2;
    cout << "The Second Polynomial is " << endl;
    cout << P2;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The addition of these is " << endl;
    A1 = (P1 + P2);
    cout << A1;
}
```

When doing Sum = P1 + P2 in main, where the three are objects, Sum returns garbage values. Why is it not possible to simply assign a returned value to an Object, like we do when dealing with primitive data types?

Creating SumObj dynamically fixes the issue, which means that the returned object gets destroyed before being passed to the assignment operator overloading function.

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Why all the manual memory management? Seems to just needlessly complicate things.

Comment: @JesperJuhl probably homework assignment to teach manual memory management...

Comment: Probably unrelated: your `operator=` corrupts objects in case of self-assignment (`P1=P1`) and leaks memory otherwise (`P1=P2`).

Comment: Please show the full implementation of `operator+`. Perhaps your `sum` is already garbage before you construct an object with it.

Comment: @Botje could you explain how it leaks memory?

Comment: You do not `delete[]` the contents of `exponents` and `coeffs` before you overwrite them.

Comment: @Botje the SumObj inside the operator+ works fine, (tested it by printing SumObj inside the function)

Comment: Well, we will need a [mre] before we can further help you then. Because you left out parts of the code that may or may not be the cause of your problems.

Comment: @Botje Edited to add complete code. (The istream and ostream operators are overloaded correctly, and have not been included)

Comment: The last large loop in `operator+` reads one past the end of the array. And I think you wanted to do `j--` instead of `i--` there. Step through the failing case in a debugger and see when the garbage values are introduces. The actual code that constructs a copy is sound so garbage must be introduced earlier.

Comment: Do you have to manage the memory yourself? `struct Term { float m_coefficient; int m_exponent; };` `class Polynomial { std::vector<Term> m_terms; public: ... };` would automatically provide you with copy&move semantics plus remove the need to write your own destructor. Also why not keep the terms in sorted as a class invariant? This would make the logic for reading a bit more complex, but it would simplify implementing arithmetic operators.

Comment: Btw: implementing both default constructor and `Polynomial(int s)` could be done in one go by simply adding a default value for `s`: `Polynomial(int s = 10) ...` You should probably be initializing the values in the arrays though; otherwise any operation on the class that results in a read on one of the arrays could easily result in undefined behaviour, if no write happens first...

Comment: You've got 3 major issues: 1. Problem logic is not clear to you yet. 2. You don't know the proper tools that C++ provides to solve your problem. 3. You are not skilled at resource management, but want to manually manage memory(also a resource). If this is more than just a class assignment, 1. clarify the logic to yourself, 2. The proper tool is `std::map`, 3. Let resource management practices for some later time with simpler problems(Read more about RAII, rule of 0/3/5 and copy-swap idiom).

Comment: This is infact a class assignment where i do need to manage memory manually as well as define parameterized constructors as well as default ones separately. :)